# Why isn't pg_restore --create working?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump, pg-restore

I backed up a database called `app_data`, on a 9.3 server, with this basic command:

```
pg_dump -n public -F custom app_data > app_data.pg.dump
```

Then I try to restore it on another server (running 9.4) like this:

```
pg_restore -C -d postgres app_data.pg.dump
```

But it puts all the tables in the `postgres` database. The man page says it will create and use a new database, `app_data`.

> -C --create
>
> Create the database before restoring into it. [...]
>
> When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data is
>              restored into the database name that appears in the archive.

That's not what it's doing. The name in the archive is `app_data`:

```
bash-4.2$ pg_restore -l app_data.pg.dump 
;
; Archive created at Tue Dec 15 04:16:52 2015
;     dbname: app_data
...
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you get errors?

Comment: No errors, it just quietly puts it all in the `postgres` database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that behaviour is something that I should report to postgres as use of different flags doesnt seem to have an effect and it just doesnt work. To solve it use:

- create DB

`createdb -h HOST -U USER -W DB_NAME`

- restore and in case of Error Stop

`egrep -v 'EXTENSION.*plpgsql' DUMPFILE.sql | psql -h HOST -U USER -W  -d DB_NAME -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1`

Answer (score 0):

> pg_restore -C -d postgres app_data.pg.dump
>
> But it puts all the tables in the postgres database

Isn't that exactly what you *asked* it to do with the "-d postgres" argument?

If you want to load a *different* database, you need to tell pg_restore so:

```
pg_restore -d app_data -C app_data.pg.dump
```